# Upload an image with AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I can't understand why this is so hard. All the tutorials and articles online seem to be talking about the 1.0 api, which is pretty useless.

I've tried a few different ways and get different results. What am I doing wrong?

1. upload task - this seems to not be using a multipart form, wtf?

   ```
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.manager.requestSerializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                                     URLString:[[NSURL URLWithString:url relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ApiBaseUrl]] absoluteString]
                                                                                    parameters:@{}
                                                                     constructingBodyWithBlock:nil];

   NSProgress *progress;
   NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [self.manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                           fromData:data
                                                           progress:&progress
                                                  completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
                                                    if (error) {
                                                      NSLog(@"[error description] = %@", [error description]);
                                                    } else {
                                                      NSLog(@"success!");
                                                    }
                                                  }];

   [task resume];
   ```
2. post with a block - this seems not to attach anything

   ```
   [self.manager POST:url
              parameters:@{}
   constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
       [formData appendPartWithFileData:data
                                   name:@"post[picture]"
                               fileName:@"picture.jpg"
                               mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
   }
                 success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id response) {
                   NSLog(@"Success");
                 }
                 failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                   NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                 }];
   ```
3. simple post - this seems to almost work...but not

   ```
   [self.manager POST:url
           parameters:@{@"post[picture][]":data}
              success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id response) {
                NSLog(@"Success");
              }
              failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
              }];
   ```

I would love 1 to work, but I'm not sure why it doesn't.

Comment: When you use an `NSURLSessionUploadTask` in step 1, where are you getting the data from ? I'm doing something similar (though not a multipart POST) by first building the request, and then using the `request.HTTPBody` as data.

Comment: have you been able to resolve this issue .. i am having same issue .. i need to send parameters with image too .. tried all three possible ways .. you mentiond .. but no one is working ... no sample is provided by afnetworking too ...

Comment: have you resolved it. I have similar question can you help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180367/afnetworking-2-2-0-upload-image-on-server-issues

Answer (score 14):

For a properly formed "multipart/form-data" body, you need to use use the body construction block while creating the request. Otherwise the upload task is using the raw data as the body. For example, in your AFHTTPSessionManager subclass:

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSURL URLWithString:kPhotoUploadPath relativeToURL:self.baseURL] absoluteString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:urlString parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:photo.data name:@"photo" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [self uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * __unused response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        if (failure) failure(error);
    } else {
        if (success) success(responseObject);
    }
}];
[task resume];
```

Or, if you don't need to track upload progress, you can simply use:

```
[self POST:kPhotoUploadPath parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:photo.data name:@"photo" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    if (success) success(responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    if (failure) failure(error);
}];
```

Comment: I'm afraid the first answer is incorrect, as `uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:` is for *streaming* requests, i.e. through a persistent URL connection.

Comment: I don't think that's what 'streamed' means in this context. It's likely just referring to the fact that it's a multi-part form request: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2 My understanding is that the request body is streamed, but the connection is not persistent and is closed once the request is completed. This is the standard request type for uploading files. `uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:` is also used by AFNetworkings `...constructingBodyWithBlock:...` methods.

Comment: @RayLillywhite but when I check my photo.data it is nil, can you look in my similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180367/afnetworking-2-2-0-upload-image-on-server-issues

Answer (score 5):

What Ray Lillywhite describes works perfectly fine (I would've made a comment on his post, but my reputation is too low).

1. Get the correct version of AFNetworking, containing [this fix for updating progress when using multipart requests](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/1617). At the moment of writing, that version is HEAD.
2. Create a `NSMutableURLRequest` with the help of `multipartFormRequestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:error:`.

   - Build your form data with the help of one of the `appendPartWith...` methods.
3. Get a (upload) data task by calling the right `uploadTaskWith...` method. You NEED to use `uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:progress:completionHandler:` if you want to use the `NSProgress` input parameter.