# AFNetworking 2.0 POST issue | replacing deprecated multipartFormRequestWithMethod:path:parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, web-services, afnetworking-2

I am migrating an iOS app from Xcode4 to Xcode7 (beta 4). Dependency to `AFNetworking` is automatically resolved via Pods. `AFNetworking` 2.0 is not backwards compatible with `AFNetworking` 1.0 so I modified part of the source. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/805783afebea1e81) is

- File structure
- Log and
- the related Source code

Issue below

```
/Api/ApiClient.m::: error: unexpected interface name 'NSData': expected expression
                NSData* callerData = [@"http://nikyotis.xyz" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                ^

/Api/ApiClient.m::: error: use of undeclared identifier 'callerData'
                NSData* callerData = [@"http://nikyotis.xyz" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

at line 280 of the example above

[image]

Substituting NSData with NSString results in the error below

[image]

Original AFNetwork-1.0 code below

[image]

I try to migrate to AFNetwork-2.0 by replacing the routine with either //1

[image]

or //2

[image]

without any success

Comment: Can you share your color theme?

Comment: im looking for answers really. color is sublime text + obj-c

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261253/upload-an-image-with-afnetworking-2-0 doesn't help

Comment: neither this https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12820

Comment: this _seems_ to work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180367/afnetworking-2-2-0-upload-image-on-server-issues

Comment: checking -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/19841957/1148542

Comment: checking -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294178/replacement-for-afjsonrequestoperation-in-afnetworking-2-x

Answer (score 7):

I think the NSData compiler error is a red herring. The problem is that you are only provided a code block for the 'failure' argument rather than the 'constructingBodyWithBlock' argument.

Try something like:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = 
[ [ApiManager sharedManager] 
POST:@"/v1/exec"
    parameters:nil
constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
        {
            // Code to form the body of the form is here

            //NSData* callerData = [[NSData alloc] init];
            NSData* callerData = [@"http://nikyotis.xyz" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [formData appendPartWithFormData:callerData name:@"caller"];
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:fontData name:@"front" fileName:@"front" mimeType:@"application/octet-stream"];
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:sideData name:@"side" fileName:@"side" mimeType:@"application/octet-stream"];
        }
       success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
        {
            // Operation success code goes here
        }

       failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
        {
            // Operation failed code goes here
        }
 ];
```

apologies for any formatting issues - having markdown trouble.

Comment: i 've already tried what you suggest - check latest screenshots with code commented out (//1, //2)

Comment: No - both of those listings have no body for the first two block arguments. Look where I have the { } sections in the answer above. In your listings (both //1 and //2) you just have one block of { } code for the last argument of the method call.

Answer (score 4):

problem was the unstable (beta)

OS X El Capitan 10.11 Beta (15A244d) | Xcode Version 7.0 beta 4 (7A165t)

I was using. what i was expecting really...

the code above runs fine on stable Yosemite n Xcode 6.4